# Can I prevent Feed Updates for inactive users of my app?

Tags: getstream-io

I just recently started diving into GetStream to add newsfeed capabilities to our Mobile App.

What is the best-practice for handling inactive users?  We have a mechanism in place that allows us to identify inactive users, so we can prevent sending emails and other notifications to these users.

I would rather inactive user feeds not receive feed-updates without having to unfollow.

Does getstream have any mechanism available to mark a feed as inactive so as to prevent it from being updated?